# Name for a special kind of submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

The submatrix obtained by removing a matrix's last $K$ rows and columns is defined as the *leading principal submatrix*. I would like to know if there is a name for the submatrix obtained by removing the **first** $K$ rows and columns of a matrix. The motivation for such submatrices is a method to reconstruct matrices which works by constructing the matrix from the end to its beginning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would be inclined to call it the “trailing principal submatrix”, though I have to admit, I’ve never come across either of these terms (but I also don’t work with matrices often so…)

Comment: @peek-a-boo, thanks for your reply. So there is no valid and general nomenclature for such matrices?

Comment: I don’t know (like I said, I don’t work with matrices often). If your goal is to write something, then the general advice to follow is to always define your terms beforehand if you think it is not a widely known term.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes I'm writing a manuscript. I think I have to define this term.

Comment: What is the motivation for this?  Why does the “trailing principal submatrix” matter?  The leading principal submatrices matter when testing for positive definiteness.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am solving an inverse eigenvalue problem to reconstruct a matrix. The construction method works from the end of the matrix not from its beginning.

Comment: Please append such motivation to the question itself